# How do I get the chest in Lotus Shoal?

Tags: oceans-heart

In Lotus Shoal, there's a chest on an area that's across a one tile gap.  However, there's one slight problem with this particular jump:

[image: One-tile gap jump in Lotus Shoal]

There is no manual jump and your auto-jump is seemingly two tiles long; attempting this jump causes you to immediately drown and respawn before the jump.

[image: I'm immediately drowning after the jump]

How do you get this chest?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to jump diagonally to get there without dying as I found out about 30 minutes after I initially posted this question.